# Secure Store Servce. Set Credentials Programmatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, secure-store, console-application

I have a problem when trying to set SSS credentials for a target application using C#. Console application is used for this task.

I can successfully create a Target Application with fields, admins and members etc. However! At the very last moment (see the code blow), when I'm trying to write credentials for a given SSS Target Application I receive an "Access denied" when using SetUserCredentials or SetCredentials methods.

Method SetGroupCredentials runs with no errors but does nothing, credentials are not set.

So, I've got two questions:

- What is a correct way to set Credentials for SSS?
- Why do I get "Access Denied" error?

**Additinal info:**

- I am a farm adiministrator
- App pool account has full control on the entire Secure Store Service app

  private void btnUpdateCredentials_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          SecureStoreServiceProxy ssp = new SecureStoreServiceProxy();

  ```
     SPServiceContext context =   SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPServiceApplicationProxyGroup.Default, SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier.Default);

     ISecureStore iss = ssp.GetSecureStore(context);

      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.SelectedRows)
      {
          MappingRow mappingRow = row.DataBoundItem as MappingRow;
          TargetApplication targetApp = new TargetApplication(
              mappingRow.SssId,
              mappingRow.SssId,
              adminMail,
              0,
              TargetApplicationType.Group,
              null);

          var userName = new TargetApplicationField(
              "User name",
              false,
              SecureStoreCredentialType.WindowsUserName);

          var password = new TargetApplicationField(
              "User password",
              true,
              SecureStoreCredentialType.WindowsPassword);

          var SSASRole = new TargetApplicationField(
              "SSAS Role",
              false,
              SecureStoreCredentialType.Generic);

          IList<TargetApplicationField> fields = new TargetApplicationField[] { userName, password, SSASRole };

          SPClaim adminBasicClaim = SPClaimProviderManager.CreateUserClaim(admin, SPOriginalIssuerType.Windows);
          SecureStoreServiceClaim adminClaim = new SecureStoreServiceClaim(adminBasicClaim);

          SPClaim groupBasicClaim = SPClaimProviderManager.CreateUserClaim(mappingRow.ReadLoginOrDomain, SPOriginalIssuerType.Windows);
          SecureStoreServiceClaim groupClaim = new SecureStoreServiceClaim(groupBasicClaim);

          TargetApplicationClaims claims = new TargetApplicationClaims(
              new List<SecureStoreServiceClaim>() { adminClaim },
              new List<SecureStoreServiceClaim>() { groupClaim },
              null);

          try
          {
              iss.CreateApplication(targetApp, fields, claims);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
             //TODO app already exists
          }

          IList<ISecureStoreCredential> creds = new List<ISecureStoreCredential>(3);
          creds.Add(new SecureStoreCredential(SecurityString.MakeSecureString(mappingRow.ShadowAccount), SecureStoreCredentialType.WindowsUserName));
          creds.Add(new SecureStoreCredential(SecurityString.MakeSecureString(mappingRow.ShadowPassword), SecureStoreCredentialType.WindowsPassword));
          creds.Add(new SecureStoreCredential(SecurityString.MakeSecureString(mappingRow.SqlRole), SecureStoreCredentialType.Generic));
          SecureStoreCredentialCollection credsColection = new SecureStoreCredentialCollection(creds);

         //Exception: Access denied An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server.SecureStoreServiceException' occurred in Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.dll
         //Access is denied to the Secure Store Service.
         iss.SetUserCredentials(mappingRow.SssId, groupClaim, credsColection);

         //Exception: Access is denied to the Secure Store Service.
         iss.SetCredentials(mappingRow.SssId, credsColection);

         //Code runs, but nothing happends:
         iss.SetGroupCredentials(mappingRow.SssId, credsColection);
      }
  ```

Comment: Which account you are using?

Comment: I am using farm account which is also app pool account, local admin and SSS admin with full control. I also use another user account wich has the same level of rights everywhere